# memory leakage in this code?

Tags: java

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sortArrayMap(ArrayList arrList)
    {
        ArrayList retArray = new ArrayList();
        Hashtable tableUnOrdered = new Hashtable();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) arrList.get(i);
            tableUnOrdered.put(map.get("TCNT"), i);
        }
        Vector v = new Vector(tableUnOrdered.keySet());
        Collections.sort(v);
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_ITEMS_PER_GRAPH && j < v.size(); j++)
            retArray.add(v.get(j)); // add the list in the needed order

        return retArray;
    }
```

I am not able to find out where memory leakage is happening in this code, can anyone let me know on this. My boss said this code has memory leakage and asked me to find out.

Comment: What do you mean by _"memory leakage"_? What's the symptoms?

Comment: I think, there is no memory leak in this code. Why do You think there is ? Please send results from  "jstat -gcutil" . Of course everybody knows that Java is one big memory leak ;-) I think problem is with heap size.

Comment: Sort array map? Why not use TreeMap?

Comment: It's not a leak; but you could substitue the Vector and Hashtable to a ArrayList and HashMap : they are both unsynchronized and probably a bit faster.

Comment: Avoid using `Vector` as vectors use much more memory

Comment: It's also possible that you would like to sort the original array rather than creating a new array?

Comment: @ karl: where are we creating a new array and what do u mean by sorting the org array

Comment: retArray is a new array(list).  The original array is the one passed as an argument. It's possible to sort that directly, using a custom comparator that would compare two maps ( using the TCNT entry in each map.)

Comment: could you repost the code with u r suggestion, it would help me a lot to learn... thx

Comment: I can't : It doesn't do what it says it does: Its returning a list of Strings, not a list of HashMaps, so I am not sure what I should do. I'll post an answer with the generics cleaned up, and you can see that it wont compile.

Comment: its fine KarlP, its a great help from you... could you see in this post whether any memory leakage is happening... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968553/does-these-code-has-memory-leakage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's broken: I cleaned up the generics, and it's not returning a list of HashMaps, its returning a list of strings.

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sortArrayMap2(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  arrList)
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> retArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> tableUnOrdered = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = arrList.get(i);

        tableUnOrdered.put(map.get("TCNT"), i);
    }
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(tableUnOrdered.keySet());
    Collections.sort(v);
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_ITEMS_PER_GRAPH && j < v.size(); j++)
        retArray.add(v.get(j)); // add the list in the needed order

    return retArray;
}
```

Comment: Thats a great help from your side... few questions alone 1. what is TCNT and where is custom comparator and is this code broken and what is the advantage of this from previous code.

Comment: can u help me in this code also, i think it will be a great day for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968553/does-these-code-has-memory-leakage

Comment: No advantage: this code does not even *compile* as the add() operation is trying to insert a String and not a HashMaps<String,String>. It means however that the code probably is not doing what you think it does.  I don't know what TCNT is more than its a key that is supposedly added to all maps in the arrList. I think you need to go back to your boss and ask for help from an experienced coder - this code is just confused and wrong.

Comment: The "generics" is that you specify whats contained in the list and maps ( basically the stuff inside the angle-brackets)  I inferred that on the lists and maps thats created using what I think is in the arguments and return variables. Generics is good because the compiler will then not allow you inserting a "wrong" data type in a list.

Answer (score 5):

This method as far as I can see doesn't hold references on some enclosing classes fields, therefore it can't cause memory leaking.

Comment: what do u mean by that?? can u explain a bit more

Comment: @John, it uses only method local variables, which will automatically get garbage collected after returning from the method. Memory can only leak in Java if a reference to some object(s) is kept for the lifetime of the app. Practically the only way to this is to (directly or indirectly) keep a reference in a `static` class member field. But there are no fields used in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the argument all variables live in method scope.  They will be marked for garbage collection when the method terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your boss if really means memory leakage, or whether he means it's using too much memory. Tell him there's a big difference and you need to know which it is he's worried about.