# solution to memory leakage in this code

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [does these code has memory leakage??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968553/does-these-code-has-memory-leakage)

```
static private       ArrayList   seriesColors      = new ArrayList(); 

public Audiogram(int widthParm, int heightParm) 
            throws Exception 
    { 
        super(widthParm, heightParm); 
        seriesColors.add(new Color(  0,   0, 255)); 

        // Set the default settings to an industrial audiogram 
        setType(INDUSTRIAL_AUDIOGRAM); 
    }
```

This piece of code causes memory leakage. What should be the change.

1. Should i change the static variable into non static.

> Generates audiogram graphs.
>
> This class is mainly used to generate
>   the standard audiogram XO graph.
>
> The audiogram graph is normally
>   displayed with the highest value at
>   the bottom (i.e. -10 on top to 110 on
>   the bottom) so that the line goes down
>   as an employee's hearing gets worse.

Comment: Waiting for the next post about memory leak:P

Comment: Are questions about memory leaks bad?

Comment: @Pete No, it is just he is posting nearly identical questions about memory leaks in a short time:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Audiogram is a constructor and seriesColors are not used apart from this method

Assuming that your statement is accurate, and assuming that you posted the entire constructor, the `seriesColors` attribute (static or not) serves no useful purpose whatsoever.

If this is the case, the then fix for the memory leak is to simply **remove** the `seriesColors` declaration from your code, as follows:

```
// static private ArrayList seriesColors = new ArrayList();  <<<=== remove this line

public Audiogram(int widthParm, int heightParm) 
        throws Exception 
{ 
    super(widthParm, heightParm); 
    // seriesColors.add(new Color(0, 0, 255)); <<<=== remove this line

    // Set the default settings to an industrial audiogram 
    setType(INDUSTRIAL_AUDIOGRAM); 
}
```

However, I suspect that this is not the whole story ...

**EDIT**

Comment out those two lines as indicated.  If the code compiles with those two lines commented out, then they are definitely redundant.

However, it strikes me that your knowledge of Java must be close to zero.  If this is the case, you should NOT be trying to clean up memory leaks and the like in other peoples' code.  Learn some Java first.

Comment: how do u say, i searched all the class for seriesColors and nothing is found...

Comment: This inspection reports instances of collection fields or variables whose contensts are either queried and not updated, or updated and not queried. such mismatched queries and updates are pointless and may indicate either dead code or typographical error.

Comment: This is what it says when i hover the ArrayList.. i mean CTRL + F1

Answer (score 3):

Well, the only way this code could "leak" memory is if you just keep adding elements to `seriesColors` without ever removing any. So, to answer your question: Remove old / unnecessary colors from `seriesColors` or avoid adding them.

Regarding the `static` modifier: You should remove `static` in front of the `seriesColors` if you want each `Audiogram` to have its own instance of `seriesColors`. If you want the `seriesColors` to be shared among all instances of `Audiogram` then you should keep it `static`.

Comment: Audiogram is a constructor and seriesColors are not used apart from this method

Comment: Then remove the variable all together...

Comment: where to remove can u just update me on this, i have updated on what the class does

Comment: If you're not accessing `seriesColors` anywhere but in this constructor, you're not *using* it. You're basically just dumping `Color`-objects into it without ever *reading* the list of `Colors`. That why I'm saying, remove the list of colors all together.

Comment: i am lost can u show me that...