# Difference between these two appraoch in calling equals method?

Tags: java

Approach one.

```
if (graphType.equals("All") || graphType.equals("ALL"))
```

Aprroach two.

```
if ("All".equals(graphType) || "ALL".equals(graphType))
```

What is the difference between these two approaches?
Why the below one is better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second one is better, as if `graphType` is `null`, the first code snippet will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Note that you can simplify your code using `"ALL".equalsIgnoreCase(graphType)` (if you accept values such as `AlL` or `aLL`...)

*Edit regarding your comment:*

If `graphType` is `null`, in the first case, you will get a `NullPointerException`. In the second case, the evaluation of the `equals` method will be `false`, as `"someString".equals(null);` always returns `false`:

Here is the code of the `String.equals(String)` method:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29))

The interesting line is `if (anObject instanceof String) {`. When you call the `instanceof` statement on a `null` object, this test always returns `false`. That's why `"anyString".equals(null);` will return `false`.

Comment: what if in latter case graphType is null

Comment: It reads like a Yoda condition though ... null should be handled explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

I feel the need to present a contrarian viewpoint to the accepted answer:

The first one is better, precisely because it will throw a NullPointerException in the case where graphType is null.

Generally, if an unexpected condition is found, you want to halt and throw an Exception as early as possible, otherwise you may continue to execute the program in an invalid state and the bug may become fiendishly difficult to track down.

This is sometimes referred to as the "[fail-fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)" principle.

Comment: That would depend if `graphType` is allowed to be `null`. If `null` is a "normal" or "usual" status, then the second is OK. If `null` indicates exceptional behaviour, then go for the first and deal with the NullPointerException.

Comment: I personally would not allow it to be null. In fact, I would not use the literal constant "ALL". I would create a `private static readonly string AllGraphs = "ALL";` or whatever the Java equivalent is, and use that throughout. At the first chance, I would convert something like `"AlL"` to `AllGraphs`. Similarly to having a constant for `"ALL"`, I would have one for `"None"`, etc.

Comment: @masher - that's true! Although in that case if null was "normal" I would still like to see an explicit check rather than implicit cleverness in order to make clear that this is a possible expected value.... otherwise some poor fool is likely to trip over this in the future

Answer (score 3):

romaintaz answer is absolutely correct.  However, if you're like me, you might prefer to use the first approach to make your code easier to read.  This is where assertions come into play:

```
assert graphType != null : "graphType is null";    
if (graphType.equals("All") || graphType.equals("ALL"))
```

The question is whether your users will find a creative way to make graphType = null once you've finished testing.

The other thing I don't like about the second approach is that it fails silently in the case that graphType is unexpectedly null -- It prevents a runtime error, but may present a bug that's difficult to track down.

Comment: assert graphType != null : "graphType is null"; What does it do and what does it check here

Comment: Assertions are used in development to test hypotheses about the state of the software at various points; they're typically turned off (i.e., ignored by the runtime engine) in deployment.  In this case, "assert graphType != null" means 'I expect graphType is not null'.  If graphType is in fact null, the runtime engine will print the specified message ("graphType is null") to System.out.  Also see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html and http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/assertions/

Comment: can u help me in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968553/does-these-code-has-memory-leakage